# Force, Newtons second law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

In the book "An Introduction to Mechanics - Second edition" by Kleppner D., Kolenkow R, I came across a paragraph:

pg. 54 , sec 2.5.2(force)

> It is worth emphasizing that force is not merely a matter of definition. For instance, if we observe that an air track rider of mass $m$ starts to accelerate at rate $\vec a$, it might be tempting to conclude that we have just observed a force $\vec F=m\vec a$. Tempting, but wrong. The reason is that forces always arise from real physical interactions between systems. Interactions are scientifically significant: accelerations are merely their consequence. Consequently, if we eliminate all interactions by isolating a body sufficiently from its surroundings —an inertial system— we expect it to move uniformly.

I can not understand why it is wrong. Please explain to me the reason author gave.

Comment: Whenever citing a book, cite it with the name of the author and mention the chapter, section, page number etc. if you're quoting something from the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the author's statement is weirdly worded to say the least. Unless Newton's laws are incorrect, you can obviously conclude that if an object is accelerating, then the net force acting on it is mass times acceleration (assuming you're in the inertial frame).

However, what the author is trying to convey is the theoretical structure of our model of the world in Newtonian mechanics. That is that we ought to think of acceleration as the consequence of the forces acting on the particle rather than the other way around. In other words, you have to have a formalism where you can calculate forces acting on a particle independently of the acceleration of the particle (say, for example, as a function of the charges of the particles and the distances between them) and then you should verify if the acceleration produced due to this force according to the formula $F=ma$ matches with the experimentally observed acceleration of the particle. If you don't have an independent way of deducing what the force acting on a particle is independent of just observing the acceleration of the particle then you'd have learnt nothing about the world. Because you'd just see some acceleration and just define a force as $ma$ but you'd have no predictive power because you didn't really say anything about how this acceleration is arising.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The author is trying to convey the message that it was not the acceleration which made us observe a force, the force was already there. In other words, **force is not the consequence of acceleration**, rather it's the other way around, **acceleration is the consequence of force**, which implies forces are more fundamental.

Comment: But why can't I conclude on seeing an acceleration that a Force must be there?
Since an acceleration will be caused only by a force as Newton's First Law suggests.

Comment: @AyushSaxena There's no problem in concluding that. But there's a problem when you conclude that the force is because of acceleration. Force is an independent entity, it's not due to acceleration, in fact it's the other way around, like I explained in my answer.

Comment: I totally understand that Force is not due to acceleration, but the other way round.
But what I believe is that Author here said that on observing acceleration, we can not conclude that we observed Force, or in other words, we can observe acceleration when there is no Force.

Comment: @AyushSaxena That's not true. In classical mechanics, $\mathbf F_{\text{net}}=m\mathbf a$ is always true.

Comment: I believe it is true only in inertial system.

Comment: @AyushSaxena It is true everywhere, if you include the relevant pseudo forces in $\mathbf F_{\text{net}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say you have two charged particles of charge $q_1$ and $q_2$. The force between them will be given by- $$\textbf {F}=\dfrac{q_1q_2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^3}\textbf{r}$$
Now, what is the cause of the force? The Field. It was the field which developed in space due to one particle, and the other particle experienced that field.
What **you** will observe will just be the acceleration of the objects. Not the force. Force was a result of the field produced. And *that* force led to acceleration, which you observed.
I think this clears your doubt.

Comment: I will observe just the acceleration only, but I will also conclude that there must be a force which is causing that acceleration, which indeed is true in your example.
But what author says is that it is wrong to conclude the same. My question is why it is wrong, as it always seems right.

Answer (score 0):

I now understand what the author is trying to say.
He is saying that by mere observation of acceleration, we can not conclude that some force is acting on the body.
It is because we can observe acceleration sometimes which is not due to any force but is merely an artifact of being in a non-inertial system.
For example, while sitting in an accelerating car, we observe a tree accelerating in opposite direction without any force because we are in non inertial frame.
To know whether an acceleration results from a real force, we need Newton's Third Law, which states that there must be an equal and opposite force in the system, if we can not find the *partner force*, the acceleration is not due to a force but only because of non-inertial system.

Comment: Yes, you're correct but there's also a meaning to author's statement in inertial frames. I posted a separate answer. Have a look.